# How to test IPython magic with nosetests

Tags: python, ipython, nose

I use nosetests for unit testing so as team, developing IPython. There are tests for built-in magic functions https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/tests/test_magic.py

The problem is that writing tests as usual, when I try to initiate IPython with something like

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ip = get_ipython()
ip.register_magics(MyMagic)
```

nosetests fail with error that `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'register_magics'`. This is because `get_ipython()` returns `None`.

In IPython tests some custom plugins solve the problem. Command `iptest` runs IPython tests, including magics. The problem is I don't understand how exactly should I run test, or where the plugin is located and how to modify it for custom magic testing. Any help will be appreciated

P.S.: I also tried to use `InteractiveShellEmbed()`, but it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For now this may be done by calling from terminal:

```
PYTHONPATH=<path/to/folder/with/test> iptest <file_with_tests_without_py>
```